# Remapping CAPS to Escape on Windows 7 without SharpKeys

Tags: remapping

I want to remap CAPS to escape (I use escape functionality all the time in many programs), but the two suggestions that seem to pop up are:

1. Hot Keys (which even the people proposing say is a pain)
2. SharpKeys - which Norton is reporting as a malicious site now

Are there any other suggestions?

Answer (score 13):

[Autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) can do this. It's quite trivial.

Make a file with the extension `.ahk`:

```
Capslock::Esc
```

Just double click to run, once you have installed Autohotkey.

It's really that easy. You can compile the script into a executable (`.exe`) to make it portable with the compiler that comes with Autohotkey.

You'll have to run this at startup somehow if you won't want to manually run it every time you restart. Adding a shortcut to the script to the `Startup` folder in the Start Menu works.

---

If you don't feel like installing Autohotkey, I've compiled the executable and uploaded it to [MediaFire](http://www.mediafire.com/?h7u81sd37ds6f4n). If you don't trust me, go ahead and make one yourself using the above script.

---

Autohotkey themselves provide some [advantages and disadvantages](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Remap.htm#registry) of using this method compared to remapping via changing some registry keys (which is what SharpKeys does, and what Piskvor describes). They also provide instructions, specifically:

- Use a (free) program such as [KeyTweak](http://webpages.charter.net/krumsick/)
- Manually editing the registry, using a .reg file as described [here](http://www.autohotkey.com/community/viewtopic.php?p=56216#p56216)

Comment: That works. Note that this requires AHK to keep running in the background.

Comment: Excellent! I prefer this solution to the registry hack that I found here: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Map_caps_lock_to_escape_in_Windows

Comment: Is there a way to map Esc or ScrollLock to Capslock? Because there are times when you actually need the capslock.

Comment: @thameera You *should* be able to just add a `Esc::Capslock` line.

Answer (score 3):

The remapkey.exe program included in the [Windows Server 2003 Resource Kit Tools](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=9D467A69-57FF-4AE7-96EE-B18C4790CFFD&displaylang=en) mentioned in [this article](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/window-on-windows/how-do-i-turn-off-the-caps-lock-key-in-windows-7/775) works nicely in Windows 7. The techrepublic article has pictures but following is a quick summery of how to remap esc to caps.

After installing the Windows Server 2003 Resource Kit Tools:

1. Open the run dialog by pressing Win+R
2. Type 'remapkey.exe' and press enter
3. Drag-and-Drop the Base Keyboard's 'Esc' button from the to the Base Keyboard's 'Caps' button.

   - Note: after releasing the 'Esc' button over the 'Caps' button on the Base Keyboard the Remapped keyboard should reflect the change.
4. Click the "Save and Exit" button. (it is the first icon on the upper left.)
5. Click through the warnings.
6. Reboot (this is windows, after all).
7. Enjoy your remapped keys without needing an extra service running all the time!

Comment: Greetings Justin, welcome to SuperUser. We generally encourage expanding on information found in links. Could you perhaps edit in a summary of the information? This way we have something even if the links go out of date.

Comment: Attempting to install "Windows Server 2003 Resource Kit Tools" on windows 7 gives a compatibility error.  I'm guess it still may work but that was enough to cause me not to install it.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the author of SharpKeys himself notes that it only creates a special key in the registry.

You could go the hard way and mess with the layout manually, or get the MS keyboard layout creator - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964665

Note also that SharpKeys has a page at CodePlex - you could get it from there: http://sharpkeys.codeplex.com/

Comment: Also, Norton's "malicious site" reporting doesn't look like a very useful feature to me - I don't trust it, as in my experience, they too often blocked legit sites and let the malicious ones slip through.

Comment: The MS Keyboard Layout Creator does not allow remapping the Caps Lock key; it is marked "Unassignable".

Comment: Ah well. Sharpkeys is obviously the superior solution then (and the layout creator seems to be intentionally crippled, as they both operate on the same registry data), but since the question explicitly and absolutely trusts Norton (which I do not), there's nothing to do.

Answer (score 0):

## **The Best Key Remapper**

(as of April 2020)

The following programs all do an adequate job.  Let me also add that there is no *best* key remapper.  You can loosely divide key remappers into 3 groups.  In the 1st group, there are programs that will help you completely remap all the keys on your keyboard.  In the 2nd group, you can remap a few keys.  In the 3rd group, programs can help you remap keys into other keys but you can also have the keys trigger macros.  The following is a list of all the programs that I know of.  If you know more, let me know and I'll add it to this list.  After the list, I divide them into 3 categories.

- Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator 1.4
- Keyboard Layout Manager
- KeyTweak
- Autohotkey
- SharpKeys

### **1. Replacing Most of or All of the Characters on Your Keyboard**

**Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator 1.4 vs Keyboard Layout Manager**
If you want to completely overhaul all the characters on your keyboard, go for Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator 1.4.  (You can also use Keyboard Layout Manager but I've heard better things about the former.)  Although it may take a little longer, using these 2 programs, instead of the smaller programs later on the list, it is worthwhile because it makes your system run much more efficiently, as opposed to remapping 30 keys individually which will apparently slow down your computer.

### **2. Switching Just a Few Keys Around**

**KeyTweak vs SharpKeys**
When you simply want to replace *one* or just a few keys, go for KeyTweak.

When would you use this?  Here is one example.  Whenever I reinstall Windows 10, I always like to remap my F1 key into F2 because F1 wastes a lot of my time.  How?  Well, pressing F1 in most programs usually brings up a help manual and your computer takes forever to do so.  It would take 10 seconds.  F2, on the other hand, is for renaming files or text which people happen to use a lot.  While working, I will press F1 by mistake, intending to press F2, and I *hate* it.  It takes like 10 seconds for the help manual to appear sometimes and I just have to wait for it to open and then close it.  I want to kill myself when I happen to press F1 again by accident.  I know some people remedy this problem by physically popping out the F1 key cap to prevent themselves from pressing F1.  Why not just remap F1 to F2 so there are 2 F2 keys next to each other?

I've used both SharpKeys and KeyTweak to do this, and KeyTweak is much easier and faster to use.  I admit KeyTweak has been discontinued for a while but it still works *perfectly*.  (It's a really simple, tiny program.  I still use it whenever I reinstall my computer.)

By the way, LifeHacker stated in a article that it wasn't portable but it's obviously the other way around.  It actually doesn't have any installer so it's only portable.  This is good because it doesn't use any resources after you remap any key.

### **3. Programming Keys to Do Anything from Triggering Another Key to Triggering a Macro.**

**AutoType.**
AutoType is the simplest program language I know of that can be used in Windows.  For example, if you want to remap F1 to be F2, your entire script will be:

F1::F2

Or, you can press F1 which will type out, "I love you." by the following script:

F1::Send I love you.

You can make a lot more complicated programs that do a lot more things.  For example, I have scripts that do the following:

- Hotkeys to open specific programs, websites, or documents.
- Hotkeys to google-search, look for synonyms, or look for definitions of selected text.
- Paste only pure text of anything copied.
- When you close the last document or window, it will automatically terminate the entire program rather than sit there open and waste resources
- Spellchecker
- Many other things.

If you're interested in learning this easy language, just download AutoHotkey from their website.  It's open-source.  If private-message me, I can send you a few of my files filled with useful simple scripts I use every day.  You can go to Autohotkey forums and people share their AutoHotkey scripts with each other.

*Yet*, despite what people have said about it, it's going to take you some time to learn to write any script.  Nothing is always easy with computers.  I agree it's an easy language but even figuring how to install the AutoHotkey program itself takes some time.  I use AutoHotkey extensively and I can tell you that it will take you hours as a beginner to learn to write just a simple script.  Think about this.  It took me hours to just type up this simple StackExchange answer!  I had to write it out.  Proofread.  Read it again and move some paragraphs around.  Fix any errors again.

Moreover, what's even worse is that you might accidentally get addicted to inventing new AutoHotkey scripts!  The program is supposed to save you time but it takes days or weeks to program some scripts. So, scripts that are supposed to increase your productivity actually have the opposite effect!

I think AutoHotkey is worth learning but it's your call.